# Eclipse CDT - Build sub directory within a project

Tags: build-process, makefile, eclipse-cdt

i would like to know if there is an option in Eclipse (CDT) to build only part of project.

my situation is i got a very large single project which consist of many sub directories, and my build system is a custom script. now if i run the custom script from the root folder of the project, it will build all the sub folders of the projects. this takes long time and i would like to have an option to instruct the CDT to execute custom build command depending in which folder is selected in the source tree. (my custom build script would build then only the content of that directory).

is there any option to perform such action in CDT? (i'm using Galileo).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom make target. There is a specific view "Make Target", where you can view/add/edit them. We use them in our project to build a single components of our project.
The catch is that you will need to create a new target for each subdirectory. The bonus is that you easily copy each target across subdirectories.

It is also a time saver to know some short-cuts by heart: (in Indigo) F9 to re-launch the last target, and CTRL+SHIFT-Q, M to display the Make Target view. ;-)

Also, you should upgrade to Indigo - provided your plugins permit this. The cdt plugin is massively improved since then.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think CDT provides this. However, do consider whether your project really is best suited to being a single project or if it might benefit from being split up into sub-projects. There might also be a performance boost to be found in your makefile; have you read the "Recursive Make Considered Harmful" essay?